# "Bad Request" (400) when using XOAUTH2 on Google's SMTP service with service account

Tags: python, smtp, google-oauth

I wanted to use Google's SMTP service to send e-mail from my Google account.

So I went to the Google API console and created a service account, i.e. `...@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, and downloaded the private certificate.

With Python, you can use the [oauth2client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2client) library to get a credentials object for such a pair: `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials`. You provide the scope `"https://mail.google.com"` for the SMTP service.

It's explained in Google's [OAuth2 with Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough) run-through documentation, except the examples there assume that you've got an "installed app", and that you'll use a web-flow to prompt a user for authorization to send e-mail from their account.

In my case, this is from my own account, so I've already got a service account set up, complete with a private certificate with which I can authorize the credentials.

This Python-script demonstrates the problem:

```
import httplib2
import smtplib
import base64
import datetime

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

http = httplib2.Http()

google_user = "some-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
google_cert = open('some-private-cert.p12', 'rb').read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    google_user, google_cert,
    scope='https://mail.google.com/',
)

credentials.refresh(http)

# To demonstrate that we've got a valid access token, let's make a
# couple of assertions:
#
# 1. The credentials have been refreshed:
assert credentials.access_token is not None
#
# 2. The access token hasn't expired (and isn't about to):
assert (credentials.token_expiry - datetime.datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds() > 60

auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (
    google_user, credentials.access_token
)

smtp_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_conn.set_debuglevel(True)
smtp_conn.ehlo()
smtp_conn.starttls()
smtp_conn.ehlo()

# Now, authenticate (but this fails):
smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string))
```

The error response is (base64-decoded):

```
{"status":"400",
 "schemes":"Bearer",
 "scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

I don't know that it's supposed to work, but I can't see why not.